# Three.js detect collision between 2 moving objects using a Ray

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, three.js

I'm making a breakout game in 3D using THREE.js and the WebGL render. I want to use THREE.Ray to detect collision between the bouncing ball and the platform at the bottom which can be controlled by you, but I'm having trouble.

I've managed to cast a ray from the platform to the ball (or other way around) but once I do that, the ball gets stuck in the middle of the screen and cannot be animated.

```
var ray = new THREE.Ray( platform.position, ball.position.subSelf( platform.position ).normalize() );
var intersects = ray.intersectObject( ball );

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) console.log(intersects[0].distance);
```

I've tried removing the `subSelf` and `normalize()` but that breaks the detection.

Here is the game and code can be found in script.js:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4531743/WebGL/Breakout-3D/index.html

If you open the console, you can see that the distance value changes if you move the panel, so that's good. But the ball cannot be animated because at every frame it's being set to that position.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4531743/WebGL/Breakout-3D/index.html#disableRay

Above is how I originally did it, just by calculating the Z position of the ball and panel and seeing if it's bigger and is inside the panel's width (x) coordinates, and if it is, bouncing it off.

The ball's bouncing is just changing the X and Z coordinates by a fixed amount every frame, and if it goes too far in either direction, reversing that amount so it goes back.

Comment: This is too much to debug. Can you make a simpler example with just the relevant code? Can you get your simple example running in a jsfiddle so it can be more easily hacked?

Comment: Sure, here: http://jsfiddle.net/g9Djn/
What I need is a ray to detect collision between platform and ball, and then if they are touching, bounce the ball off.

Comment: How to use THREE.Ray to detect collision between the red ball and the green platform?

Comment: Try to add the collision code yourself to the fiddle. You are doing OK so far. :-) If you are still having problems, then re-post.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g9Djn/1/ This is as far as I can get. I can detect the distance between them, but now you can't move the green platform and it moves into the middle.

Comment: Hah! http://jsfiddle.net/g9Djn/2/ I've managed to do it, I think. However if the ball hits the panel from the side and not straight from the top, it behaves very weirdly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some playing around I worked it out.

```
var ray = new THREE.Ray( ball.position, new THREE.Vector3(ball.position.x, ball.position.y, platform.position.z).subSelf( ball.position ).normalize() );

var intersects = ray.intersectObject( platform );

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

    var face = intersects[0].face.d,
    dist = intersects[0].distance;

    if(face == 4 && dist <= 7) sizes.ball.velocityZ = -sizes.ball.velocityZ;

};
```

Basically, that way I'm always projecting a ray straight down from the ball, and if the platform is directly below it and the distance to the platform is close enough, I reverse the direction of the ball.

Comment: This is very helpful. But now is 2019, so threejs has been changed. We can use this

`var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(ball.position, new THREE.Vector3(ball.position.x, ball.position.y, platform.position.z).sub(ball.position).normalize());`

Use _Raycaster_ instead Ray, and _sub_ instead subSelf.

Answer (score 4):

There is an example of collision detection at:
http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Collision-Detection.html

for instructions on how to move the cube, see:
http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/#collision-detection